# Oracle Database 11g Express: associate job to window scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create a job and associate it to a couple of windows (WEEKNIGHT_WINDOW & WEEKEND_WINDOW), but I don't see any windows parameter in the Oracle doc. when creating a job:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             IN VARCHAR2,
   job_type             IN VARCHAR2,
   job_action           IN VARCHAR2,
   number_of_arguments  IN PLS_INTEGER              DEFAULT 0,
   start_date           IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL,
   repeat_interval      IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT NULL,
   end_date             IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL,
   job_class            IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   enabled              IN BOOLEAN                  DEFAULT FALSE,
   auto_drop            IN BOOLEAN                  DEFAULT TRUE,
   comments             IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT NULL);
```

This is the Oracle version I am using:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300)

The parameter you are looking for is:

```
schedule_name
```

> The name of the schedule, window, or window group associated with this
>   job.

I believe you can pass the window directly to the schedule_name, or you can do it the complicated way by:

```
CREATE_GROUP 

ADD_GROUP_MEMBER
```

> where you can add one or more windows to an existing window group
>    (the old method was ADD_WINDOW_GROUP_MEMBER)

then pass the group to schedule_name.